# Appium: Do we have a common attribute for Android and iOS to check for text value of a certain element?

Tags: android, ios, appium, appium-android, appium-ios

I'm currently torn on whether this is verifiable or not. First, I think there is some way to get the attribute value from a mobile element. However, after my observation I noticed they have two different attribute names, `text` for **Android** and `value` for **iOS**. O_O Our team is currently aiming to do one script for both Android and iOS by accessing the elements using `accessibility ID`. But... we have a test case that needs to verify if changes where correct after saving. Do we have a way to do this?

Note: We are running this in Saucelabs and Github Actions. One test script for both Android and iOS.

Android:
[image]

iOS:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your tests with page factory (Page Object design pattern), this way you can specify one WebElement with a different selector per platform:

```
@iOSXCUITFindBy(accessibility = "yourSelector")
@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "yourSelector")
    private WebElement yourWebElement
```

Text / value can be read by one and the same method for both platforms like so:

```
yourWebElement.getText();
```

(Examples in Java)
Documentation [here](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/docs/Page-objects.md).